# How to put set of words in to an array using python

Tags: nlp

Sorry for the inconvenience since I'm new to Python. I have set of words as follow.

**Hi

Rex

studied

university

interested

Java**

Those words are placed in line by line. I want to put those words into an array using Python. The output should be as **Hi Rex studied university interested Java** How could I get my expected result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the words are in a file called "file.txt"

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    output = [line.strip('*\n') for line in f]
```

Then to print the list of words:

```
for words in output:
    print(words, end=' ')
```

To write these back into a new file. Format as needed.:

```
with open('newfile.txt') as f:
    for words in output:
        f.write(words)
```

Comment: I got those words as a result of removing stop words. So how can I put those words into a file.txt?

Comment: updated answer to include writing list of words to a file.